# 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend' and there is no answer for me

Tags: python, facebook, intellij-idea, facebook-prophet

I want to use Facebook's prophet,however when I try to create a model:

```
model = prt.Prophet(stan_backend='CMDSTANPY')
```

It occurs mistake like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\IdeaProjects\station-simulate\stcd-predict.py", line 24, in <module>
    model = prt.Prophet(stan_backend='CMDSTANPY')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 142, in __init__
    self._load_stan_backend(stan_backend)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 153, in _load_stan_backend
    self.stan_backend = StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(stan_backend)()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.model = self.load_model()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 79, in load_model
    return cmdstanpy.CmdStanModel(exe_file=model_file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\model.py", line 192, in __init__
    do_command(['where.exe', 'tbb.dll'], fd_out=None)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\utils\command.py", line 53, in do_command
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

If I don't use `stan_backend='CMDSTANPY'`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\k6789\IdeaProjects\station-simulate\stcd-predict.py", line 24, in <module>
    model = prt.Prophet()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._load_stan_backend(stan_backend)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my1stconda\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 154, in _load_stan_backend
    logger.debug("Loaded stan backend: %s", self.stan_backend.get_type())
AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'
```

I re-setup prophet with micromamba and it has no effect.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I changed another computer and created a new conda environment，solved this.